# MKMapView swift custom annotation view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, swift

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s301/sh/75701c23-ae05-498e-a44d-5e3481d3a492/1aaedebaf244e8f260ede49360360bc0/deep/0/MapViewController.swift---Edited.png

why I have this errors? And also I know that in this code I haven't reused a "pinView". How correct load a "pinView" from xib with reused identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that line not confirms to `NilLiteralConvertible` protocol.

Use:

```
let pinView : UserAnnotationView ? = //yourAssignment here
```

For more info check [Swift Literal Convertibles](http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/)

Comment: look please. this code is good? or maybe I can use another way. https://www.evernote.com/shard/s301/sh/6fddf2ac-d958-4ea1-8cee-a31cc17678dd/5412f871031d3434129e104985fbb1dd/deep/0/MapViewController.swift.png Also, I don't know how here I can load nib with reuse identifier